# Why there is delay in receiving Tibco EMS consumer destroy event?

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

Tibco EMS

Created subscriber over $sys.monitor.consumer.create and 
$sys.monitor.consumer.destroy

subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic,"target_dest_name like 'xyz.%'", true);

filtering out events based on destination name.

Create event is received as soon as consumer is created on this queue xyz.1

Destroy event is received 15 mins after consumer is destroyed.

Why there is delay in receiving Tibco EMS consumer destroy event ?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere, or are you just dumping random text on the web?

Comment: edited question to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this delay was due to tcp keep alive and tcp keep interval and tcp keep probes on the operating system.